# Representative manifold of $\mathbb{Z}_4^T$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, cobordism

I want to know which manifold is the *representative manifold* (I do not know the correct terminology in math) $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_4^T$ in the following sense:

$\mathcal{M}$ is unorientable, and has a $\mathbb{Z}_4$ bundle on it, defined by
$$f: \mathcal{M}\rightarrow B\mathbb{Z}_4$$
such that given the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ cohomology ring of $\mathbb{Z}_4^T$ being $\mathbb{F}_2[a, b]/(a^2)$ where $a,b$ are at degree 1 and 2, respectively, $f^*(a) = w_1(\mathcal{M})$ and $f^*(b^2)[\mathcal{M}] = 1$, where $w_1$ is the Stiefel-Whitney class of $\mathcal{M}$ and $[\mathcal{M}]$ is the top-form of $\mathcal{M}$.

I briefly hear that it should be the twisted product of two Klein bottles, but I want to know the detailed construction.